# How to map 2 objects with 4 different property classes?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 6 classes and I want to mapp them with AutoMapper

```
 public class Alert
        {
                public string MessageSender { get; set; }
                public Site Site { get; set; }
                public IEnumerable<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }
        }

public class AlertModel
    {
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public SiteModel Site { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<RecipientModel> Recipients { get; set; }
}


public class Site
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

public class SiteModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

public class Recipient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CallId { get; set; }
    }

public class RecipientModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CallId { get; set; }
    }


    private static void ConfigureAlertMapping()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            cfg.CreateMap<Alert, AlertModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Sender, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MessageSender))
        );
    }

    private static void ConfigureRecipientMapping()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Recipient, RecipientModel>());
    }

    private static void ConfigureSiteMapping()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Site, SiteModel>());
    }
```

This is the object which I want to map.

```
Alert alert = new Alert()
        {
            Site = new Site() { Id = 1 },
            Recipients = new List<Recipient> { new Recipient() { CallId = "1001" } }
        };
```

I want to call this but throw an exception... :(

```
AlertModel alertOutputInfo = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Alert, AlertModel>(alert);
```

**This is the error:**

```
>>Mapping types:
Alert -> AlertModel
UniteAlerter.Domain.Models.Alert -> UniteAlerter.Gateway.Models.AlertModel
   at lambda_method(Closure , Alert , AlertModel , ResolutionContext )
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
   at UniteAlerter.Gateway.AlertGateway.<SendAlert>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

If you will find another solution, please add it here.

Comment: Can you provide your mapping config as well

Comment: Sure, you need to scroll down first code comment (last 3 methods).

Comment: I call those methods in one named Configure which is called in Startup -> ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

Comment: you should add your solution as an answer then set it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**

I found the problem... I initialize mapper for every class which I wanted to map, but the solution is to initialize mapper one time with all mappings.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(
cfg =>
     {
        cfg.CreateMap<Alert, AlertModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.Sender, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MessageSender));
        cfg.CreateMap<Recipient, RecipientModel>();
        cfg.CreateMap<Site, SiteModel>();
      }
);
```